# Check list equality in R, all.equal doesn't return true

Tags: r, list, comparison, equality

I am trying to check whether rows in a dataframe are equal based on only 4 elements of the df. I subset the dataframe for the 2 rows and 4 elements I want to compare, and end up with 2 lists.

When I use `all.equal` or `identical` on the 2 lists, they do not return as being equal. However, if I cycle through each element in the 2 lists and compare them using "==", each element comparison returns as equal.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
    first <- df[row, c("elem1", "elem2", "elem3", "elem4")]
    second <- df[row+1, c("elem1", "elem2", "elem3", "elem4")]
    if (isTRUE(all.equal(first, second))) {
      df[row, "diff_element"] <- 1
    }
}
```

When I print `str(first)` and `str(second)`, they're identical. I can't figure out why at least all.equal doesn't return as true.

Here is part of the df:

```
   elem1 elem2 elem3  num1      num2    num3    num4 elem4 diff_element
1 103404   BRJ    CJ 55.89  17.70005 107.017 77.0330   Car            0
2 103404   BRJ    CJ 55.89  17.70005 107.017 77.0330   Car            0
3 355309   CLK    JR 12.00 223.44000  23.000 20.2234 Train            1
```

Here's what I get when I check the structure (for the first 2 rows, which should be equal):

```
> str(first)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ elem1: int 103404
 $ elem2: Factor w/ 2 levels "BRJ","CLK": 1
 $ elem3: Factor w/ 2 levels "CJ","JR": 1
 $ elem4: Factor w/ 2 levels "Car","Train": 1
> str(second)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ elem1: int 103404
 $ elem2: Factor w/ 2 levels "BRJ","CLK": 1
 $ elem3: Factor w/ 2 levels "CJ","JR": 1
 $ elem4: Factor w/ 2 levels "Car","Train": 1
```

Comment: We'd need a sample of the `df` dataset in your question to answer your question.

Comment: With regards to `identical` the two objects really need to be _exactly_ identical, e.g. this returns `FALSE`: `identical(list(a=1, b=2), list(b=2, a=1))` ... are you sure your objects are _exactly_ identical?

Comment: @lebelinoz I added the first few rows of the data frame